# how to use string replace in byte mode python

Tags: python

The code:

```
def readFasta(filename):
    """ Reads a sequence in Fasta format """
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    header = ""
    seq = ""
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if (line == ""):
            break
        if (line.startswith(b'>')):
            header = line[1:].strip()
        else:
            seq = fp.read().replace(b'\n',b'')
            seq = seq.replace(b'\r',b'')          # for windows
            break
    fp.close()
    return (header, seq)

FASTAsequence = readFasta("MusChr01.fa")
```

the b before the '' are necessary because I'm in bytes mode.  The problem is that when run, fp.read.replace and seq.replace delete everything in the string.  I do know that read is working correctly because

```
def readFasta(filename):
    """ Reads a sequence in Fasta format """
    fp = open(filename, 'rb')
    header = ""
    seq = ""
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if (line == ""):
            break
        if (line.startswith(b'>')):
            header = line[1:].strip()
        else:
            seq = fp.read()
            break
    fp.close()
    return (header, seq)

FASTAsequence = readFasta("MusChr01.fa")
```

works perfectly fine.  What's going on here?

Comment: Assuming you are using Python3 from your comments about byte mode. You should also have a `b""` for the initial values of `header` and `seq`

Comment: Also, `line == ""` should be `line == b""`.

Comment: I believe you should use text mode and not binary mode. If you have to deal with newlines it means your file is a text file, not a binary file. If this is not the case then your binary format is broken by design and you'd better create a new file replacing all `\r\n` to `\n` and use that instead.

Comment: Ok so it turns out it was the length of the file that was the problem.  It was actually working fine just that print couldn't handle the size of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner way to write your function. Not sure why it wasn't working for you yet though

```
def readFasta(filename):
    """ Reads a sequence in Fasta format """
    header = seq = b""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if not line:
                break
            if line.startswith(b'>')):
                header = line[1:].strip()
            else:
                seq = fp.read().translate(None, b'\r\n')
                break
    return (header, seq)
```

Comment: b' b' to be exact, one two different lines.

Comment: Can you add a small sample file that fails to your question?\

Comment: Oh it actually works with small files.  Maybe the actual problem is the fact that the file in question is 190 mb.

Comment: The `not line` condition cannot be true in any iteration (otherwise the `for` would have stopped already) and the `break` after `fp.read()` is useless too since in the next loop the file-pointer will be at the EOF and the `for` will stop automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In `else` block, the code does not consider `line`. Try following.

```
def readFasta(filename):
    header = b""
    seq = b""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        while True:
            line = fp.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if line.startswith(b'>'):
                header = line[1:].strip()
            else:
                seq = line + fp.read() # <--- without `line +`, you lose a line.
                seq = seq.translate(None, b'\r\n')
                break
    return header, seq
```

Example with [a sample sequence from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format):

```
>>> with open('mchu.fasta', 'rb') as f: print(f.read().decode('ascii'))
... 
>MCHU - Calmodulin - Human, rabbit, bovine, rat, and chicken
ADQLTEEQIAEFKEAFSLFDKDGDGTITTKELGTVMRSLGQNPTEAELQDMINEVDADGNGTID
FPEFLTMMARKMKDTDSEEEIREAFRVFDKDGNGYISAAELRHVMTNLGEKLTDEEVDEMIREA
DIDGDGQVNYEEFVQMMTAK*

>>> readFasta('mchu.fasta')
(b'MCHU - Calmodulin - Human, rabbit, bovine, rat, and chicken', b'ADQLTEEQIAEFKEAFSLFDKDGDGTITTKELGTVMRSLGQNPTEAELQDMINEVDADGNGTIDFPEFLTMMARKMKDTDSEEEIREAFRVFDKDGNGYISAAELRHVMTNLGEKLTDEEVDEMIREADIDGDGQVNYEEFVQMMTAK*')
```

Comment: That still doesn't explain why `seq` contains stuff in the second version of the function

Comment: @gnibbler, No, it does not. It's strange.

Comment: Looks like that line should definitely be included though.

Comment: It might have to do with the file size.  The file is 190mb and ends up running out of memory actually when I let it run all the way.